Files disappear from project menu few seconds after opening in PyCharm
I downloaded a repository as a zip file from GitHub and I want to open it in PyCharm, which I installed specifically for this task. My problem is that when I open the folder in PyCharm, the files disappear from the left menu after a few seconds.
It is not a repo I am supposed to modify and then push or something my task is just to run tests for coverage.
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling PyCharm, deleting et redownloading the repo, deleting the .idea folder, invalidating caches in PyCharm but none of this works.
Can someone please help me with this issue ?
You can find a picture of what PyCharm looks like after the files disappear.

Something outside PyCharm is deleting the files. The project menu simply updates to match what's in the real folders.

@Barmar The files are still in the folder when I open it from my desktop.
